# insert a MYSQL 5.7 point representation of latitude,longitude into a table

Tags: mysql, latitude-longitude

I have a table geom as follows:

```
id (Int) not null (pk),
name (varchar 25),
timestamp (timestamp),
lat (decimal 6,4),
lon (decimal 6,4),
g (geometry),
pt (point)
```

I have another process that populates the lat,lon fields.

I want to populate the pt field to take advantage of 5.7's geospatial extensions

if I fat finger the lon,lat into the following insert statement is works fine:

```
set@g='point( -80.00 40.00)';

insert into geom (pt,timestamp) values (pointfromtext(@g),now());
```

but I would like to use the values stored in that record's lon,lat fields

I can create  what looks like the right value using a concat statement but the insert  "pointfromtext" statement will not take the result

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create MySQL spatial column - Point Data type with lat long without using Alter table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39612856/create-mysql-spatial-column-point-data-type-with-lat-long-without-using-alter)

Answer (score 0):

Construct SQL using, among other things,

```
CONCAT("point(", lon, ",", lat, ")")
```

`lon` needs `DECIMAL(7.4)` if you expect to cover the entire world.

Comment: thank you very much here is the query that worked thanks looking at this & also the info about the decimal structure:                                               set @g=(select CONCAT("point(", lon,' ',lat, ")") as a from geom where id='13');
insert into geom (pt,timestamp) values (pointfromtext(@g),now());