# Create MySQL spatial column - Point Data type with lat long without using Alter table

Tags: mysql, spatial

How can I create a MySQL spatial column with "Point" Data type using latitude & longitude using a CREATE statement. (Without using Alter)

Do I need to store latitude and longitude as well or can I insert both values into the Point(x,y) field and get rid of the latitude/ longitude columns? The examples that I have read till now retain the lat long fields.

Please share some examples.

Answer (score 1):

The point field has both the latitude and longitude data stored inside it and they can be retrieved quite easily if required. Assuming your point field is name pt, the following query gives this information.

```
SELECT ST_Y(pt), ST_X(pt) FROM my_spatial_table;
```

This is exactly the same as doing

```
SELECT Y(pt), X(pt) FROM my_spatial_table;
```

since [X and ST_X](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-point-property-functions.html) are aliases. So in short you only need the point field.

You can add your pt field as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN GEOMETRY;
```

Then you can move the data from the existing latitude, and longitude columns as follows:

```
UPDATE my_table SET pt = PointFromText(CONCAT('POINT(',longitude,' ',latitude,')'))
```

For more details on this please see:   https://stackoverflow.com/a/7135890/267540
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/populating-spatial-columns.html

Comment: How do I create such a table? create mytable (pt point)? and how do I insert values into this table?

Comment: No, I haven't. I'm still resolving some other issues in my code.

Comment: Please help me merge these statements into one create statement.
How can I achieve the following in the create statement? - UPDATE  mytable SET mycol= Point(lon, lat);

Comment: The answers is that you cannot combine DDL and DML queries into a single statement. They always have to be executed separatedly (regardless of whether geospatial data is used or not)