# How do I properly insert latitude & longitude coordinates into mySQL float?

Tags: mysql, precision, sqldatatypes

I am trying to insert something like `150.1835024` and `32.8392648` into mySQL as `float`. The problem is when I try to create a mySQL field like `FLOAT 3,7` it doesn't work. What's the proper format?

This is the error I get:

```
An error occurred when trying to add the field 'location_lat' via

 ALTER TABLE `data` ADD `location_lat` FLOAT(3,7)
 NULL
 DEFAULT NULL
 AFTER `fees`

MySQL said: For float(M,D), double(M,D) or decimal(M,D), 
M must be >= D (column 'location_lat').
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39612856/create-mysql-spatial-column-point-data-type-with-lat-long-without-using-alter/39613104#39613104

Comment: 7 decimal places is enough to distinguish one ant from another.  (Overkill.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the error as it says *MySQL said: For float(M,D) .. M must be >= D* and with that your query should actually be

```
ALTER TABLE `data` ADD `location_lat` FLOAT(7,3)
```

Go through [MySQL Documentation On Floating-Point Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/floating-point-types.html)

> MySQL permits a nonstandard syntax: FLOAT(M,D). Here, (M,D) means than
>   values can be stored with up to M digits in total, of which D digits
>   may be after the decimal point.

Comment: Now it makes sense to me. Didn't earlier. Must get sleep. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 3):

The first number is the total number of digits, both the the right and to the left of the decimal.  The second number is how many digits you want to the right of the decimal. So you're looking for:

```
ALTER TABLE `data` ADD `location_lat` FLOAT(10,7)
```

Comment: The correct answer should be this. float(10,7) not float(7,3) below

Answer (score 0):

Do *not* use `FLOAT(m,d)`, simply use `FLOAT`.  The former adds an extra round that buys you nothing.

A `FLOAT` takes 4 bytes in either case.